# Entity Framework with SharpDevelop

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sharpdevelop

I want to use EF with SharpDevelop to conect with a MySQL Database. I've added all the MySQL referentes possible, but when I try to create a connection, just the option for MS SQL Server appears. Could someone help me?

Comment: Please add some code or an image of your problem to better help you

Answer (score 0):

SharpDevelop currently only has support for SQL Server.